# How to convert unix timestamp to iso 8601 in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, timestamp

I am getting date from a server as a `unix timestamp`, how can I convert it to `ISO 8601` date format in flutter?

the date I receive:

> 1611694800000

How I want to convert it to be

> 2021-01-26T22:00:00.000+00:00

What I have done so far with no luck

```
    String s = '1611694800000';
    debugPrint("Recevied date is: $s");
    String dateS = DateTime.parse(s).toIso8601String();
    debugPrint("Converted date : $dateS");
    String dateStr = (dateS.split(".")[0].split("T")[0] + " 00:00:00").substring(1);
    debugPrint("Activation date: $dateStr");
```

I end up getting:

> Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Invalid date format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.1/dart-core/DateTime/DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch.html):

```dart
var timestampMilliseconds = 1611694800000;
var datetime =
    DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(timestampMilliseconds, isUtc: true);
print(datetime.toIso8601String()); // Prints: 2021-01-26T21:00:00.000Z
```

(Note that the printed time is one hour off of your stated expectation, but I'm assuming that's a mistake in your expectation.)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting invalid date format is because you have to provide date in string like '2021-04-19' and not milliseconds;

This package makes it easy to format dates [time_formatter](https://pub.dev/packages/time_formatter)